# Having difficulty working with 3 layer highchart donut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm using jquery `Highcharts` donut plugin in my website to display `security incident taxonomy`. The format of taxonomy is as (much like unordered list).

- **Inside** //source level 0

  - **type**

    - Login abuse
    - access voilation

      **- detection method** level 2

      - user
      - siem

  **- Outside // source**

  - **type**

    - Login abuse
    - access voilation

      **- detection method**

      - user
      - siem

The working example I have as **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kSc6G/)** on here, I have been able to pull only 2 circles one for **source** and other for **attack type(e.g login abuse)**. What I want is this infact

Inside(20%) -> access(17%) -> siem (some %).

Is there I can customize highchart to allow me give three circles / levels of distribution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fiddle with the `size` and `innerSize` attributes of the series. The `size` tells highcharts how big the circle is overall, and the `innerSize` tells it how much to cut out of the center. So, if you wanted to add a layer to the outside of your circle chart, you'd need a new series with this:

```
size: '100%',
innerSize: '80%',
```

[Fiddle for demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/kSc6G/2/)

Comment: Thanks @Sam but here is the problem the last series you added the data  is initialized with attacktype array which is holding information from about different types instead I want to have information under detection method appear in the last series level (3). Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just change the data series to the one you need.

Comment: thxs what confusion is drilldown which i copied from offical highcharts code side, I guess I don't need drilldown option I can just specify in the series code space.